# Allow only numeric entry in WPF Text Box

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm

I will like to validate user entry to ensure they are integers. How can I do it? I thought of using `IDataErrorInfo` which seems like the "correct" way to do validation in WPF. So I tried implementing it, in my ViewModel.

But the thing is my text box is bound to an integer field, and there isn't any need to validate if an `int` is an `int`. I noticed that WPF automatically adds a red border around the textbox to notify the user of the error. The underlying property doesn't change to an invalid value. But I would like to notify the user of this. How can I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a TextBox to only accept numeric input in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268552/how-do-i-get-a-textbox-to-only-accept-numeric-input-in-wpf)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The red border you've seen is actually a ValidationTemplate, which you can extend and add a info for the user. See this example:

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="validationTemplate">
            <Grid>
                <Label Foreground="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center">Please insert a integer</Label>
                <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Red">
                    <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>

<TextBox Name="tbValue" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}">
```

Comment: where to add usercontrol?

Answer (score 18):

Another way is simply to not allow values that are not integers.
The following implementation is a little bit sucky, and I would like to abstract it later on in order for it to be more reusable, but here is what I did:

in the code behind in my view (I know this is might hurt if you are a hardcore mvvm ;o) )
I defined the following functions :

```
  private void NumericOnly(System.Object sender, System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = IsTextNumeric(e.Text);

}


private static bool IsTextNumeric(string str)
{
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex reg = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[^0-9]");
    return reg.IsMatch(str);

}
```

And in the XAML view, every textbox that was only supposed to accept integers
was defined like this:

```
   <TextBox Padding="2"  TextAlignment="Right" PreviewTextInput="NumericOnly" Text="{Binding xxx.yyyy}" MaxLength="1" />
```

The key attribute being PreviewTextInput

Comment: this wont handle  blank spaces . how can i handle dem?

Comment: IsTextNumeric returns true for non numeric text.  A more readable solution would be to change the regex to [0-9] and set e.Handled = !IsTextNumeric, so the event is bubbled up when the text is numeric.  That or change the method name to IsTextNotNumeric :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1268648/419348 It introduces the same method. Moreover, it prevent pasting incorrect data.

Answer (score 9):

We can do validation on text box changed event.
The following implementation prevents keypress input other than numeric and one decimal point.

```
private void textBoxNumeric_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
        TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
        Int32 selectionStart = textBox.SelectionStart;
        Int32 selectionLength = textBox.SelectionLength;
        String newText = String.Empty;
        int count = 0;
        foreach (Char c in textBox.Text.ToCharArray())
        {
            if (Char.IsDigit(c) || Char.IsControl(c) || (c == '.' && count == 0))
            {
                newText += c;
                if (c == '.')
                    count += 1;
            }
        }
        textBox.Text = newText;
        textBox.SelectionStart = selectionStart <= textBox.Text.Length ? selectionStart : textBox.Text.Length;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are working in WPF Better to use PreviewTextInput event which support all platforms and from presentationcore.dll

here is the example:

```
private void TextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Text) == null || !(e.Text).All(char.IsDigit))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to create a numeric field in WPF, using the regular expressions.

XAML:

```
<TextBox PreviewTextInput="NumberValidationTextBox"></TextBox>
```

Code behind:

```
private void NumberValidationTextBox(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
Regex regex = new Regex("[^0-9]+");
e.Handled = regex.IsMatch(e.Text);
}
```