# How to force textbox to take only numbers in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, textbox

I want user to enter only numeric values in `TextBox`.

I got this code:

```
private void txtType1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
     int isNumber = 0;
     e.Handled = !int.TryParse(e.KeyChar.ToString(), out isNumber);
}
```

But I am not getting `textbox_KeyPress` event and `e.KeyChar` while using WPF.

Whats the solution in WPF?

**`Edit:`**

I made a Solution!

```
private void txtName_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    CheckIsNumeric(e);
}

private void CheckIsNumeric(TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    int result;

    if(!(int.TryParse(e.Text, out result) || e.Text == "."))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Got It Was Really Help full.. It worked....

Comment: [View here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268552/how-do-i-get-a-textbox-to-only-accept-numeric-input-in-wpf) You can find here a good overview of answers for it.

Answer (score 18):

```
protected override void OnPreviewTextInput(TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        char c = Convert.ToChar(e.Text);
        if (Char.IsNumber(c))
            e.Handled = false;
        else
            e.Handled = true;

        base.OnPreviewTextInput(e);
    }
```

Comment: Good answer! Although, I would replace all but the last line of your method body with e.Handled = !Char.IsNumber(Convert.ToChar(e.Text));

Comment: `PreviewTextInput()` will not catch the 'space' key press. Adding `if (e.Key == Key.Space) e.Handled = true;` in the `PreviewKeyDown()` would solve that problem.

Comment: This answer doesn't solve problem of user pasting a value into the textbox. The pasted value could contain letters.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a validation rule...
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpfvalidation.aspx

Or make your own Maskable textbox
http://rubenhak.com/?p=8

Answer (score 1):

You can bind your textbox with a dependency property and inside dependency property's validation method you can check if int.tryparse returns true then fine otherwise you can go for default or you can reset value.

Or you can use WPF ValidationRules to find out when the value is changed. Once changed you can apply logic for inout validaiton.

Or you can use IDataError Info for validation.

Answer (score 1):

bit enhanced version of Hasib Uz Zaman

```
     private void txtExpecedProfit_PreviewTextInput_1(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckIsNumeric((TextBox)sender,e);
    }

    private void CheckIsNumeric(TextBox sender,TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        decimal result;
        bool dot = sender.Text.IndexOf(".") < 0 && e.Text.Equals(".") && sender.Text.Length>0;
        if (!(Decimal.TryParse(e.Text, out result ) || dot )  )
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

this will check for duplication .(decimal mark) and will not allow just only .(decimal mark)

Answer (score 1):

```
//Call this code on KeyDown Event
if((e.Key >= Key.NumPad0 && e.Key <= Key.NumPad9) || (e.Key == Key.Back))
{ e.Handled = false; }
else if((e.Key >= Key.D0 && e.Key <= Key.D9))
{ e.Handled = false; }
else
{ e.Handled = true; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In WPF the keycode values are different from the normal winforms e.keychar values,

In the PreviewKeyDown event of the textbox, add this code:

```
if ((e.key < 34) | (e.key > 43)) {
if ((e.key < 74) | (e.key > 83)) {
    if ((e.key == 2)) {
        return;
        }
    e.handled = true;
    }
}
```

This will allow the User to only enter Numbers in the Numpad0 - Numpad9 section and the D0 - D9 and also the key.Back

Hope this Helps, cheers!

Comment: not working in conjunction to Shift. You can insert special characters

Answer (score 0):

```
private void shomaretextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
  // xaml.cs code
  if (!char.IsDigit(e.Text, e.Text.Length - 1))
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

In xaml

```
<TextBox x:Name="shomaretextBox" 
         HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
         Height="28" 
         Margin="125,10,0,0" 
         TextWrapping="Wrap" 
         VerticalAlignment="Top" 
         Width="151" 
         Grid.Column="1"        
         TextCompositionManager.PreviewTextInput="shomaretextBox_PreviewTextInput" />
```

Comment: Better if you could add some explanation, dome details, not code only. The idea is that other users could also benefit from your answer as well (in the future), not only the OP. Just a thought :)

Answer (score -1):

I believe what you're looking for is the [`PreviewTextInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewtextinput.aspx) event.