# Number only TextBox (WPF)

Tags: wpf, textbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get a TextBox to only accept numeric input in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268552/how-do-i-get-a-textbox-to-only-accept-numeric-input-in-wpf)

The following codes are not correct :

```
 private  void txtCode_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = !AreAllValidNumericChars(e.Text);



    }
    private bool AreAllValidNumericChars(string str)
    {
        foreach (char c in str)
        {
            if (!Char.IsNumber(c)) return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

**and**

```
 private  void txtCode_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = !AreAllValidNumericChars(e.Text);

    }
    bool AreAllValidNumericChars(string str)
    {
        bool ret = true;
        if (str == System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.CurrencyDecimalSeparator |
            str == System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.CurrencyGroupSeparator |
            str == System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.CurrencySymbol |
            str == System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NegativeSign |
            str == System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NegativeInfinitySymbol |
            str == System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator |
            str == System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberGroupSeparator |
            str == System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.PercentDecimalSeparator |
            str == System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.PercentGroupSeparator |
            str == System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.PercentSymbol |
            str == System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.PerMilleSymbol |
            str == System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.PositiveInfinitySymbol |
            str == System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.PositiveSign)
            return ret;

        int l = str.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
        {
            char ch = str[i];
            ret &= Char.IsDigit(ch);
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

**and**

```
     private override void txtCode_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        char c = e.Text.ToCharArray().First();
        e.Handled = !(char.IsNumber(c) || char.IsControl(c));

    }
```

and .....

The problem : Ctrl+V   Copy/Paste

What is the correct code?

Comment: I believe everything you want know is in this reference: http://karlhulme.wordpress.com/2007/02/15/masking-input-to-a-wpf-textbox/ Especially, read the last part.

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268552/how-do-i-get-a-textbox-to-only-accept-numeric-input-in-wpf can help.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I used for number only textbox and is working fine.

```
private void textBox1_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = onlyNumeric(e.Text);
}

public static bool onlyNumeric(string text)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex("^[0-9]*$"); //regex that allows numeric input only
    return !regex.IsMatch(text); // 
}
```

Comment: OP Stated WPF in the title and used C# in their example.