# How to permit all numeric keys

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get a TextBox to only accept numeric input in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268552/how-do-i-get-a-textbox-to-only-accept-numeric-input-in-wpf)

I have a textbox that i only want to accept numeric keys aswell as delete and backspace.

I can allow delete and backspace easily enough, but is there a way to permit all numeric keys as a group (something like Key.Numeric) instead of doing them invidually? Im using wpf so its windows.input.key instead of forms.key.

Answer (score 1):

If you are searching for masked text box for WPF you can try [this](http://wpfdevelopertools.codeplex.com/) library. 
[Here](http://www.progware.org/Blog/post/Masked-TextBox-in-WPF-%28and-Keyboard-in-WPF%29.aspx) you can find an example of implementation.

Ps Ive found some old sample of such a textBox. You need to hook up to textChanged event. I know its not a perfect solution but might give you basic idea:

```
int state = 0;
private void IPAddressTxtBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
            if (state != 1)
            {
                char[] allowedChars = new char[] { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '.' };
                string inputText = this.IPAddressTxtBox.Text;

                string result = "";
                foreach (char c in inputText)
                {
                    if (allowedChars.Contains(c))
                    {
                        result += c.ToString();
                    }
                }
                if (!this.IPAddressTxtBox.Text.Equals(result))
                {
                    this.IPAddressTxtBox.Text = result;
                    this.state = 1;
                    this.IPAddressTxtBox.SelectionStart = this.IPAddressTxtBox.Text.Length;
                }

            }
            else if (state == 1)
            {
                state = 2;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The numerical keys are labelled `D0` ... `D9` but you prpbaly don't want to rely on this being sequential enum values.

You can create a static lookup:

```
static HashSet<Key> numKeys = new HashSet<Key> { Key.D0, ... };  

   if (numKeys.Contains(k)) ...
```