# numeric TextBox keydown

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, numeric, keydown

i want to make a TextBox numeric. The Idea is to check the pressed Key before the Text is shown in the TextBox. I implement the Method KeyDown() of the TextBox.
Here is my Code:

```
private void txtX_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

KeyEventArgs has no KeyChar (I got this from a tutorial)

I use **WPF**

Comment: I think you're going about it the wrong way, have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268552/how-do-i-get-a-textbox-to-only-accept-numeric-input-in-wpf

Comment: Anyway, what's your actual question? KeyEventArgs has a Key property to see what is pressed.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. There are plenty of examples of numeric textboxes on the Internet.

Comment: [KeyPress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx) event has [KeyPressEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.aspx) parameter which contains KeyChar property. Resume - use KeyPress event instead KeyDown

Comment: @Reniuz He's using [WPF TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox_events.aspx). There is no KeyPress event.

Comment: @Ray so where did SO get idea about KeyChar property?

Comment: @Reniuz Who's SO? He read a tutorial for WinForms when he's using WPF (as tagged by the question) which is the whole problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For windows form

`e.SuppressKeyPress = !(e.KeyValue >= 48 && e.KeyValue <= 57);`
For wpf

`e.Handled = !("D1D2D3D4D5D6D7D8D9D0".Contains(e.Key.ToString()));`

Im using VS2010
Using the same logic U can do a better solution, more elegant :)

Comment: There's no SuppressKeyPress. WPF not WinForms.

Comment: ups,i dont see the tag wpf :(

Comment: other solution for wpf using the same idea is 
e.Handled = !("D1D2D3D4D5D6D7D8D9D0".Contains(e.Key.ToString()));

Comment: The problem with your solution is, that the char 'd' is allowed in the textbox.

Comment: `e.Handled = (e.Key < Key.D0 || e.Key > Key.D9) && (e.Key < Key.NumPad0 || e.Key > Key.NumPad9);`

Answer (score 0):

I consider that ***KeyEventArgs*** don't have ***KeyChar*** property. You can check the

***KeyEventArgs*** defintion as below.

```
public class KeyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    // Fields
    private bool handled;
    private readonly Keys keyData;
    private bool suppressKeyPress;

    // Methods
    public KeyEventArgs(Keys keyData);

    // Properties
    public virtual bool Alt { get; }
    public bool Control { get; }
    public bool Handled { get; set; }
    public Keys KeyCode { get; }
    public Keys KeyData { get; }
    public int KeyValue { get; }
    public Keys Modifiers { get; }
    public virtual bool Shift { get; }
    public bool SuppressKeyPress { get; set; }
}
```

And you can try to covert key value to char, please reference the sample as below.

```
private string keyChar = string.Empty;

// Convert KeyValue to char
private void SomeKeyDown(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    keyChar = (char)e.KeyValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WinForms, the easiest way to filter characters are in the KeyPress event.

```
private void txtX_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```
private void txtbox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = !("D1D2D3D4D5D6D7D8D9D0".Contains(e.Key.ToString()));  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you do this:

```
        if (e.Key == Key.D)
            e.Handled = true;
        else
            e.Handled = !("D1D2D3D4D5D6D7D8D9D0".Contains(e.Key.ToString()));
```

:D