# User can't type '.' in the textbox that have been bound to a float value while UpdateSourceTrigger is PropertyChanged in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a funny problem with `Float` data type and `UpdateSourceTrigger` in `WPF`.I have a property with float data type and  bind it to a `TextBox` and set `UpdateSourceTrigger` of the Binding to `PropertyChanged`,but `WPF` dosen't let me type '.' in the `TextBox` unless i change `UpdateSourceTrigger`  to `LostFocus`.I think it's because of we can not type '.' in the end of float value.I don't have any idea how can i fix it because i need to type '.' and set `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged`.

The property is:

```
  public float? Amount
    {
        get;set;
    }
```

And in the XAML:

```
    <TextBox
        Text="{Binding Amount , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: Duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14600842/bind-textbox-to-float-value-unable-to-input-dot-comma/35942615#35942615

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it would help if you add a StringFormat statement in your binding:

```
<TextBox
    Text="{Binding Amount, StringFormat='{}{##.##}', UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Update: I saw that my first answer throws some binding errors..

An other option is working with a converter (works, but a bit dirty ;-) ):

```
...
<Window.Resources>        
    <local:FloatConverter x:Key="FloatConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
...
<TextBox Text="{Binding Amount, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource FloatConverter}}"></TextBox>
```

Converter:

```
public class FloatConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
     return value;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
     // return an invalid value in case of the value ends with a point
     return value.ToString().EndsWith(".") ? "." : value;
  }
```

}

Comment: This problem is a Net5 bug,the is no problem with typing dot in float values in net4.5.And this answer wont let user to type zero after dot.

Comment: Yoy may fallback to the previous behaviour, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/35942615/254109

Answer (score 1):

This is because binding to a float data Type will automatically cause WPF to add a `float validator`. You can bypass this problem by use a different `DataAnnotation` for your `float` property or write your own `Validator`.

http://wpf-4-0.blogspot.de/2012/12/data-annotations-in-wpf-c.html

edit:
I see you have a `nullable float`, so you can also try to set the `TargetNullValue`to ".".

Comment: Then what's the advantage of setting TargetNullValue to "."??!

Answer (score 1):

If you have .NET 4.5 or newer, you may enforce the pre 4.5 behaviour

```
System.Windows.FrameworkCompatibilityPreferences.KeepTextBoxDisplaySynchronizedWithTextProperty = false;
```

With .NET 4.5 it is no longer possible to enter a separator character (comma or dot) with `UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged` by default.

Also you can have a delay :

```
<TextBox Width="100" Margin="10" Text="{Binding DoubleField, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Delay=500, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}">
```

And another way is use IValueConverter:

```
public class DoubleToPersistantStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private string lastConvertBackString;

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value is double)) return null;

        var stringValue = lastConvertBackString ?? value.ToString();
        lastConvertBackString = null;

        return stringValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value is string)) return null;

        double result;
        if (double.TryParse((string)value, out result))
        {
            lastConvertBackString = (string)value;
            return result;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

check this link:
[Binding to double field with validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223236/binding-to-double-field-with-validation)

But i think the best way is that you set `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `LostFocus`.

Comment: +1 Delay=500 to sidestep the validation issue and still keep the updatesourcetrigger to propertychanged.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a StringFormat definition to the binding. Like so:

```
<TextBox Name="txtPower" Height="23" 
TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=Power, Mode=TwoWay, 
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,StringFormat=N2}"></TextBox>
```