# Validation Errors causing binding to not update

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I was dabbling in WPF and noticed a peculiarity that I had never seen before. In the example below I have two text boxes that are bound to the same DP in the code-behind.

Code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(Window), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("Hello"));

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


}
```

And the XAML:

```
    <TextBox>
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding RelativeSource = "{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}" Path="Text" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Mode="TwoWay">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <utils:RestrictInputValidator Restriction="IntegersOnly" ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"/>
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
    <TextBox Name="TextBox" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, Mode=TwoWay, Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

I noticed that when I type something in the TextBox that contains the IntegerOnly validation which fails the validation (in this case anything that is not an integer), the underlying Text variable does not update. **Is this a default behavior? Why does it do this? Is it possible to override?**

[image: Error example]

Comment: Why would you add validation if you're going to override it?

Comment: I wouldn't, you are right. But there might be an obscure use case in which I need to look at the dirty data in the code-behind.

Comment: Where do you need your validation? Do you need it for users? Or do you just need it for final input? If you need it for latter, just add a button and pop up a `MessageBox` that says which field is wrong and not continue until all validation passes. Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1268648/1466627).

Answer (score 0):

Set the ValidationStep of the ValidationRule to CommitedValue, which will run the validation after the value has been committed to the source ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validationstep.aspx)).

```
<utils:RestrictInputValidator Restriction="IntegersOnly" ValidationStep="CommitedValue" ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"/>
```

edit:
With validationstep set to CommitedValue or UpdatedValue, a BindingExpression is sent to the Validate-method and not the actual value. I don't know if there is another way to get the value of a BindingExpression, but I made an extension method that will get it:

```
public static class BindingExtensions
{
    public static T Evaluate<T>(this BindingExpression bindingExpr)
    {
        Type resolvedType = bindingExpr.ResolvedSource.GetType();
        PropertyInfo prop = resolvedType.GetProperty(
            bindingExpr.ResolvedSourcePropertyName);
        return (T)prop.GetValue(bindingExpr.ResolvedSource);
    }
}
```

Comment: Although I thought this would work, this makes my code throw an `InvalidCastException` even when I change my Restriction to `Restriction="None"` (which essentially means do not validate).