# Text input validation for textbox in .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, validation, events

I want to validate (in some simple way) if the input text for a textbox is a number, I would use this code: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12721673/1252575)

But here's a problem: I use `.NET 4.0` not `4.5`, so I don't have`PreviewTextInput` event.

I could use `TextChanged`, but now it doesn't have `e.Handled` validator.

Is there any simple solution for this (I want to avoid tons of code)?

Comment: Can't you just use tryparse ?

Comment: use a masked textbox, then you need no validation

Comment: can you use the `char.IsNumeric` function much easier in my opinion

Comment: Use `TryParse` and deal with the exception. Or, if you wish to be adventurous, try RegEx! For just validation that it is a number, RegEx is actually pretty simple.

Comment: @DJKRAZE Wouldn't `char.IsNumeric` only work with single digit numbers?

Comment: @danielu13: If it works for single numbers making it work for an entire string is trivial.

Comment: it will work on a string if the `OP` wants to check the whole string char by char in a for loop or foreach loop

Comment: @danielu13 - A simple way to address your concern would be to convert the `String` into a `char` array and check each element of the array if its a number.  You could strip certain characters away from the string to prevent it say failing when `999-999-9999` was entered.

Comment: I wanted to cancel the event if it's not numeric. Im not retarded:D I know how to check if the string is a number. But I wanted to know if I should remember the old value of the textbox, then validate the new, if not a number, write the old. `PreviewTextInput` supports event cancellation, but it's not available in 4.0 framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to the property that will hold the value, you can use a DataAnnotation on the property.

```
[RegularExpression(Pattern="[0-9]+")]
public string MyProperty { get; set; }
```

This [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) article goes abit more in depth about the subject.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to determine what a number is and isn't. I would use `TryParse`. If it fails it's not a number.

```
string s = "12345";

int number;
bool result = int.TryParse(s, out number);

if(!result)
{
    // not a number.
}
```

Comment: Ye, but I said I don't have `e.Handled` validator. So I can't escape the event I thought there's some simple way to do this. Like `PreviewTextInput` in 4.5