# In WPF, does PreviewTextInput always give a single character only?

Tags: c#, wpf

When handling the `PreviewTextInput` event of a TextBox in WPF, can the Text property of the event argument (`TextCompositionEventArgs`) contain other than the last character input via the keyboard?

I gave it a thorough test and it seems to contain only the single character value of the last pressed key. However, I'm probably missing something obvious, as its type is `String` and not `Char`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [UIElement.PreviewTextInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewtextinput.aspx) documentation.

> The keyboard is the primary means of PreviewTextInput; **but speech,
> handwriting, and other input devices can also generate
> PreviewTextInput**.

I would assume that non-keyboard sources are able to provide more than one letter at a time.

Comment: I will add.
When inserting / replacing from the buffer and when deleting, the selection will immediately change the range of characters.
There are also cases (no example comes to mind) when one action will change several ranges in a line.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as the name explains, it previews every input which most times happens to be single character.

Using the TextCompositionEventArgs, you can access the new text with e.Text.

Or,
If you want the whole text, you can get it like

```
string full = myTextBox.Text.Insert(myTextBox.CaretIndex, e.Text);
```

Comment: myTextBox = e.OriginalSource as TextBox

Comment: This does not work when the text in the textbox is selected and would  therefore overwrite instead of insert.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it only gives you the last chararcter which is pressed.

Answer (score 2):

I found this question with the need to be check the resulting text within the TextBox through the PreviewTextInput.

The problem with Gowshik's answer and Gevo12321's comment in AMS's anwser is it doesn't account for the user selecting part of the text and overwriting it with a single character (as pointed out by hakamairi)

To account for this I removed the selected part, prior to inserting the new character

```
TextBox tB = (TextBox)sender;
var oldText = tB.Text;
oldText = oldText.Remove(tB.SelectionStart, tB.SelectionLength);
string newText = oldText.Insert(tB.CaretIndex, e.Text);
```

But, the next edge case is people selecting part of the text and dragging and dropping it in another position. For this I added an event handler to the `PreviewDrop` event, and rebuild and check the resulting string

```
TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;

// Get the index position of the dropped text
Point position = e.GetPosition(textBox);
int index = textBox.GetCharacterIndexFromPoint(position, true);

// Remove the selected text, then insert it into the new position
var oldText = textBox.Text;
oldText = oldText.Remove(textBox.SelectionStart, textBox.SelectionLength);
string newText = oldText.Insert(index, textBox.SelectedText);
```

The last edge case I could think of is people pasting into the TextBox, but for my case I disabled the functionality as it wasn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

it will only give you the character you have pressed, how ever you can get the complete text from the textbox Text property itself like `var text = (sender as TextBox).Text`

Comment: Unfortunately, that seems to only return the text as it was *before* the event.

Comment: @Dragomok if you want to get the full text, you can get the TextBox, get the addition, and add it into the correct location: `String newText = (sender as TextBox).Text.Insert((sender as TextBox).CaretIndex, e.Text)

Comment: @Gevo12321 this won't cover all the edge cases, i.e. replacing existing text.