# Which is the way Better way to override the Behaviour of a WPF control - Adding event handlers in code behind or adding Behavior class for the same

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

Recently I encountered a problem in my custom numeric control, which can take double values. But in certain scenarios it must be restricted to take only integers. Here, I have 2 ways to do it. Either handle it in the textchangedeventhandler of the textbox or create a behavior class for the custom Numeric textbox. I need to understand which one is better as per performance, standards and scalability. I also went through this link [How do I get a TextBox to only accept numeric input in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268552/how-do-i-get-a-textbox-to-only-accept-numeric-input-in-wpf). But need more specific answer as per standards.

Comment: MVVM? Pure MVVM - behaviors, *dirty* MVVM (or not MVVM) - events. Other option is to make custom control.

Comment: My advice is to handle the textinputevent of your custome numeric control and handle the behavior to have either Duoble or Interger using a Regex

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is this.  I prefer composition over inheritance.  There are many discussions on the web regarding this (irrespective of technology).  Perhaps start by reading this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

So, when I want to change the behaviour of a WPF control, I will normally use an attached property (or Behavor if you so wish) as my initial hook.  In some cases I then have complex modifications where I then have a whole 'listener' class monitoring and reacting to input on the control.

However, there are times when you may need to get at a protected member of a control.  If this cannot be avoided then inheritance it is.

So, architecturally I would say prefer an attached property (or Behavor) first, inheritance second.

Comment: Just a footnote to say that attached propety route is not strictly composition.  I guess my point is, I just like to avoid inheritance where possible.