# How to only allow to input number even on japanese keyboard using C# WPF on tablet

Tags: c#, wpf

I have problem aboet input number in japanese keyoard which everyone's help.

I have project by C# WPF run on tablet, I want to only allow to input number on my textbox, and I did this on English keyboard.
But when I change to japanese keyboard, I can input character and smile symbol.

Please help me only to allow to input number even on japanese keyboard

Comment: Please provide a bit of the code that worked on an English keyboard, so we can figure out what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Check answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268552/how-do-i-get-a-textbox-to-only-accept-numeric-input-in-wpf).
According to that you need to handle PreviewTextInput event of TextBox like so: `<TextBox PreviewTextInput="PreviewTextInput" />.`
Then inside of it you should set if the text isn't allowed: `e.Handled = !IsTextAllowed(e.Text);`

```
private static bool IsTextAllowed(string text)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex("[^0-9.-]+"); //regex that matches disallowed text
    return !regex.IsMatch(text);
}
```

If you want to check user's paste input as well, then you should hook up DataObject.Pasting event as well. So your xaml would look like:

```
<TextBox PreviewTextInput="PreviewTextInput" 
           DataObject.Pasting="PastingHandler" />
```

And PastingHandler:

```
private void PastingHandler(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.DataObject.GetDataPresent(typeof(String)))
    {
        String text = (String)e.DataObject.GetData(typeof(String));
        if (!IsTextAllowed(text))
        {
            e.CancelCommand();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        e.CancelCommand();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Are using **MVVM** if so you should have property bound to your text box, the simplest way to control the allowed values is to check them in the setter

```
   int text;
    public int Text 
    {
        get
        {
            return text;
        }
        set
        {
            // you can check whatever you want here 

            // for example

            if (value % 2 != 0)
                return;
            text = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

xaml:

```
<TextBox x:Name="NumericTextBox" PreviewTextInput="OnPreviewTextInput"/>
```

xaml.cs:

```
private void OnPreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = new Regex("[^0-9]+").IsMatch(e.Text);
}
```