# How to create numeric Textbox Custom Control with dependency Property in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I want create a custom control for Numeric Text box  with dependency property in WPF , in my solution , I add one WPF application and custom control (WPF) ,then in public class , I create dependency property ....

Now I don't know how can i write my rule for text box and which event is true?

Another question : What is my rule for numeric text box , that this text box must be give **number** and **.** and **Separating** .this  custom Text box is for accounting system.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty NumberTextbox; 
static Numeric()
{
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Numeric), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Numeric)));
    FrameworkPropertyMetadata metadata = new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("Enter Your Text", OnKeyDown);
    NumberTextbox =DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(TextBox), typeof(FrameworkElement), metadata);
}


public string NumberTXT
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(NumberTextbox); }
    set { SetValue(NumberTextbox, value); }
}
```

Comment: i wrote this event for my rule but it is not true in my metedata???

Comment: protected override void OnKeyDown(DependencyObject o, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            //System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex reg = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[^0-9]");
            //if (reg.IsMatch(NumberTXT))
            //{
            //    e.Handled = true;
            //}

            base.OnKeyDown(e);
            if (e.Key >= Key.D0 && e.Key <= Key.D9 )
            {

                e.Handled = true;

            }

Comment: If you have additional information, you can *edit* your answer instead of *commenting* it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to you add another Dependency Property in example code below I named it Value
Also format your number by comma or NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator
and control caret location changes by two property SelectionLength and SelectionStart.
Finally for more detail and complete code [WPF Maskable Number Entry TextBox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/333636/WPF-Maskable-Number-Entry-TextBox)

## region Value property

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(double), typeof(NumericTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(new Double(), OnValueChanged));

    private static void OnValueChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        //var numericBoxControl = (NumericTextBox)sender;
    }
    public double Value
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); Text = value.ToString("###,###,###"); }
    }
```

## endregion

```
    protected override void OnPreviewTextInput(TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreviewTextInput(e);
        var txt = e.Text.Replace(",", "");
        e.Handled = !IsTextAllowed(txt);
        if (IsTextAllowed(txt))
        {
            if (Text.Length == 3)
            {
                Text = Text.Insert(1,",");
                SelectionLength = 1;
                SelectionStart += Text.Length;
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
        if (e.Key == Key.Back)
        {
            if (Text.Length == 5)
            {
                Text = Text.Replace(",", "");
                SelectionLength = 1;
                SelectionStart += Text.Length;
            }
        }
    }



    protected override void OnTextChanged(TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {            
        var txt = Text.Replace(",", "");
        SetValue(ValueProperty, txt.Length==0?0:double.Parse(txt));
        base.OnTextChanged(e);
    }

    private static bool IsTextAllowed(string text)
    {
        try
        {
            double.Parse(text);
            return true;
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand your question exactly and why you need dependency proerties to make a numeric text box custom control. What you can do is to inherit from textbox and handle the PreviewTextInput, like it is solved in [this question by Ray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268552/how-do-i-get-a-textbox-to-only-accept-numeric-input-in-wpf):

then you get:

```
  public class NumericTextBox : TextBox
  {

    public NumericTextBox()
    {
      PreviewTextInput += NumericTextBox_PreviewTextInput;
    }

    void NumericTextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
      e.Handled = !isTextAllowed(e.Text);
    }

    private static bool isTextAllowed(string text)
    {
      var regex = new Regex("[^0-9]+");
      return !regex.IsMatch(text);
    }
  }
```

And you can use it like that:

```
 <myNameSpace:NumericTextBox />
```

And now you can add any other validation you want.

I would also implement a solution for the pasting issue, something like (see also in the link):

```
private void textBoxPasting(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
    {
      if (e.DataObject.GetDataPresent(typeof(String)))
      {
        var text = (String)e.DataObject.GetData(typeof(String));
        if (!isTextAllowed(text))
        {
          e.CancelCommand();
        }
      }
      else
      {
        e.CancelCommand();
      }
    }
```

Comment: any body don't know about this?

Answer (score 0):

Good job, but let me do the following task with a UserControl in C #:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace NumericBox
{
    public partial class NumericBox : TextBox
    {
        public NumericBox
        {
            this.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
            this.Text = "0,00";
            this.KeyPress += NumericBox_KeyPress;
        }

        public double NumericResult
        {
            get{
                double d = Convert.ToDouble(this.Text.Replace('.', ','));
                return d;
            }
        }
        private void NumericBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && (e.KeyChar != '.'))
                e.Handled = true;

            if ((e.KeyChar == '.' && (sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1))
                e.Handled = true;

            if (e.KeyChar == 13)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```