# Prevent WPF validation of control

Tags: wpf, validation

I'm trying to bind a `property` value to a `TextBox`.

The `property` is of type `int`, and the user can type any text they want.

If the user were to type in a non-numeric value, I can see an exception is thrown in the Output window. This makes sense.

I've added a new control, which inherits from `ValidationRule` and I call that instead (which removes the exception). However, it doesn't really help as I don't think I can change the value (the value the user entered).

What I'd like to do within the `ValidationRule` is take the bogus value the user entered and remove non valid characters. EG, if they enter `3d` I'd like the `d` to be automatically removed. The issue I have is that the signature clearly only returns a `ValidationResult`

```
public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
```

Also, is there a way to know which property is being validated. When the code is in the Validate function (shown above), I'd like to know which property is being validated!

Comment: You could change the text in the TextBox's `LostFocus` event. You don't want to change it in `TextChanged`, because that'll be changing it while the user is typing and that's exceedingly hard to make usable. Another approach is the "masked text box" approach: Handle `KeyDown` and simply refuse to accept any characters other than 0 through 9.

Comment: I think you should handle it at the TextBox, not in the validation. That is, don't let the TextBox ever take invalid characters. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268552/how-do-i-get-a-textbox-to-only-accept-numeric-input-in-wpf

Comment: Even that post does suggest the [validationrule](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1268575/3252861)