# Textbox that accepts upto 4 digit decimals

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm looking to accept digits and the decimal point for forms, using WPF application.

I am new to WPF

I want a textbox that takes only numeric values, in the format

> 12.3456

that is, 2 places before decimal point and 4 places after it.

Comment: see  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753962(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: better use specialized controls, like [DoubleUpDown](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DoubleUpDown&referringTitle=Home) from wpf toolkit

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1268648/5453249) answer

Comment: how to use Regex for getting format of this particular type 12.3456 @croxy

Comment: @Mayur95 I'm not a regex pro, but this should do the trick `^[\d]{2}([.][\d]{4})$`

Comment: no it's not working showing error for d saying unrecognized escape sequence @croxy

Comment: Pass the regex string like this: `new Regex(@"^[\d]{2}([.][\d]{4})$");`

Comment: Its not getting displayed in the above format, also it is taking strings as well. @croxy

Comment: Any thing i can do to display text in textbox in the format 12.1234?

Answer (score 0):

Too bad TextBox has no Property to set the DataType of the field and the amount of Decimal Places it can hold, had to make a UserControl that does exactly what you want.

Offtopic aside, use [Regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx), I usually use [this website](http://regexr.com/) to build them.