# How can I get a WPF field name from sender to avoid code duplication and hardcoded element names?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm writing some code to sanitise input. For examples sake, let's use the following (*note that I know to use PreviewInput for numerics, this is just for examples sake*):

```
static bool IsDigitsOnly(string str)
{
    return str.All(c => (c >= '0' && c <= '9') || c == '.');
}

private void KeyUpTextBoxNumberCheck(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsDigitsOnly(TextBoxExternalReferralOther1.Text))
    {
        TextBoxExternalReferralOther1.Text = "";
    }
}
```

I'm trying to update `KeyUpTextBoxNumberCheck` so it can work with multiple textboxes. How can I update it so that the textboxes aren't hardcoded and instead come from the sender?

Comment: Try to use [AllowableCharactersTextBoxBehavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268552/how-do-i-get-a-textbox-to-only-accept-numeric-input-in-wpf) this will be more easy for reuse, just attach behavior to textbox you need and supply it with regex and max characters count.

Comment: Can't edit last comment due to 5 mins :(( If `KeyUpTextBoxNumberCheck` binded to you textbox event, then `sender` is textbox you are looking for. You could use it as `!IsDigitsOnly((sender as TextBox).Text)`

Comment: @Shakra Oh that's fantastic! Thought it might be a simple fix but was coming up short on Google. Would you mind posting as an answer so I can accept for future visitors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [AllowableCharactersTextBoxBehavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268552/how-do-i-get-a-textbox-to-only-accept-numeric-input-in-wpf) this will be more easy for reuse, just attach behavior to `TextBox` you need and supply it with regex and max characters count.

If you want to use shown code and `KeyUpTextBoxNumberCheck` is binded to TextBox event, you cant change it to :

```
private void KeyUpTextBoxNumberCheck(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsDigitsOnly((sender as TextBox).Text))
    {
        (sender as TextBox).Text = "";
    }
}
```