# Unable to set a textbox property from string to int

Tags: xaml

I am unable to set the newly created textbox string format. By default it is considering the textbox format property as string. But i need to change the format to Int and Double for some textboxes. I am creating these textboxes on xaml page silverlight application. Highly appreciate the responses.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should convert the string after the input, not in the textbox itself. If you want to do it on the textbox itself, you should take a look at this: [How do I get a TextBox to only accept numeric input in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268552/how-do-i-get-a-textbox-to-only-accept-numeric-input-in-wpf)

Comment: I am using the existing xaml page to add new columns and rows to the existing rows and columns. I have no idea about WPF. I am doing copy paste the existing textboxes and changing the row and column numbers. This will create a new textbox but i am unable to set the format property. The view code option was grayed out when i right click on the text box. I am doing this on Visual Studio 2010.