# Regex real number

Tags: c#, regex, wpf, visual-studio

I need real numbers in `TextBox`. I try my code online [here](https://regex101.com/)

> "^-{0,1}[0-9]{1,3},{0,1}[0-9]{1,2}$"

and its working perfectly, but in my project not working.
Please show me how I must do it

Comment: Please show your code, we don't know why it isn't working without seeing the code.

Comment: you can try the [Gu.Wpf.NumericInput](https://github.com/JohanLarsson/Gu.Wpf.NumericInput)

Comment: private void c_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex ("^-{0,1}[0-9]{1,3},{0,1}[0-9]{1,2}$");
            e.Handled = regex.IsMatch(e.Text);
        }

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268552/how-do-i-get-a-textbox-to-only-accept-numeric-input-in-wpf

Answer (score 0):

Would `TryParse` works for you? From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Converts the string representation of a number in a specified style and culture-specific format to its double-precision floating-point number equivalent. A return value indicates whether the conversion succeeded or failed.

And for you, it could be something like this:

```
private void c_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    double num;
    e.Handled = double.TryParse(e.Text, out num);
    // if e.Text is a number, e.Handled will be true and num = e.Text
}
```