# How to make the Textbox numeric in wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, numeric

I want to make a TextBox as numeric, I tried this function:

```
   <TextBox Name="txtProductId" PreviewTextInput="Number_Validation"/>


   public static void Number_Validation(object sender,System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionEventArgs e)
   {
       System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[^0-9]+");
       e.Handled = regex.IsMatch(e.Text);
   }
```

But it accepts 'Space' and number. I don't need the space.

Comment: `^[0-9]*$`, try that.. or `[\d]`

Comment: when I use `^[0-9]*$` it accept anything letter and number, `[\d]` doesn't work for me

Comment: You can cut and paste samples from other SO answers. EG https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268552/how-do-i-get-a-textbox-to-only-accept-numeric-input-in-wpf

Comment: Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1268648/51882339) it gives you the opportunity to accept numeric values only in a textbox.

Answer (score 0):

"^[0-9]+" . The ^ should be outside

Comment: when ^ is outside it accept anything letter and number

Answer (score 0):

In the RegEx you need to define that between you start (`^`) and end (`$`) of the input, decimal characters only are valid, in this case the expression looks like

```
^\d+$
```

To check your specific requirements use [Regex101 Online](https://regex101.com/r/IgvXLB/1).