# WPF How to change the entered character when clicking on the textbox?

Tags: c, wpf, winforms

I have a code from WinForms that, when pressing a key on a textbox, checks which character is entered and if it is a dot, then it changes to a comma, and if it is something else, then it is checked whether it is a digit or not

```
private void textbox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        char ch = e.KeyChar;
        if (ch == '.')
        {
            e.KeyChar = ',';
        }
        if ((!Char.IsDigit(ch)) && (ch != ',') && (ch != '.') && (ch != 8))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

How do I implement such code on WPF

Now the code is like this:

```
<TextBox 
        PreviewTextInput="NumberValidationTextBox"
        />

private void NumberValidationTextBox(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex("[^0-9,.]+");
        e.Handled = regex.IsMatch(e.Text);
    }
```

In the TextBox, you can now enter numbers, a dot and a comma, it remains only to change the dot to a comma, as an option to use the textchanged event, but since I need this event for another code where the dots will already be changed to commas, then using this event is not an option.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do what you are asking, depending on what your use case is. Can you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: What value of `e.Key` will be equal to a point and what value will be equal to a comma?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you post what you have tried so far in WPF so we can see how it compares to your Winforms code?

Comment: added new code.

Comment: Well, firstly, there is no KeyPress event in WPF, and secondly, it works crookedly, a dot is put, then when you click on another dot, the text input is moved to the beginning, the dot changes to a comma, but a new one is put @Ibrennan208

Comment: There is also a code that changes a dot to a comma, but together with other code it does not work correctly 
```Regex regex = new Regex(",");
            if (regex.IsMatch(e.Text))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                testTexBox.Text += ".";
                testTexBox.CaretIndex = testTexBox.Text.Length;
            }```

Comment: sorry, I had copied the wrong method from your code. I fixed that. If you are looking for a KeyPress event, there is a KeyDown you can subscribe to as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot, by trial and error, I made a working code @Ibrennan208

Comment: Another question is, how can I accept my answer as correct if he writes to me that I can accept it within two days? @Ibrennan208

Comment: The problem is relevant again, I don't know why, but now there are only commas, although everything worked correctly before restarting the project @Ibrennan208

Comment: The problem is clear, if you change the comma to a dot, then everything works correctly, and if vice versa, then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a result, this code works:

```
private void NumberValidationTextBox(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex("[^0-9,.]+");
        e.Handled = regex.IsMatch(e.Text);
        Regex regex1 = new Regex(",");
        if (regex1.IsMatch(e.Text))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            tb1.Text += ".";
            tb1.CaretIndex = tb1.Text.Length;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are able to cast the sender as a `TextBox` and then set the text that way? Like:

```
    private void NumberValidationTextBox(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
            Regex regex = new Regex("[^0-9,.]+");

            e.Handled = regex.IsMatch(e.Text);


            if (sender is TextBox textbox)
            {


                var currentText = textbox.Text;

                textbox.Text = currentText.Replace('.', ',');
            }
    }
```

It's difficult to figure out what your intent is here.

You may just want to subscribe to the `TextChanged` event on your text entry and modify the information as it comes in. Within that method you should be able to update the text to your liking, and confirm that the text is valid.

See Microsoft's documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/textbox-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#detect-when-content-changes).

Here is an example of how you might do it:

```
<TextBox TextChanged="Entry_TextChanged"/>
```

```
private void Entry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
        //textBox.TextChanged -= Entry_TextChanged;
        //textBox.Text = textBox.Text.Replace(".",".");
        //textBox.TextChanged += Entry_TextChanged;
}
```

Further research shows Microsoft has documentation on Binding Validation, which I believe will suit your case. You can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-binding-validation?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Here's an example of how to implement a validation rule in WPF, where the XAML shows the instantiation of the `ValidationRule` object, and the C# shows how that `ValidationRule` was implemented:

```
<TextBox Name="textBox1" Width="50" FontSize="15"
         Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}"
         Style="{StaticResource textBoxInError}"
         Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="2">
  <TextBox.Text>
    <Binding Path="Age" Source="{StaticResource ods}"
             UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" >
      <Binding.ValidationRules>
        <c:AgeRangeRule Min="21" Max="130"/>
      </Binding.ValidationRules>
    </Binding>
  </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

```
public class AgeRangeRule : ValidationRule
{
    public int Min { get; set; }
    public int Max { get; set; }

    public AgeRangeRule()
    {
    }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        int age = 0;

        try
        {
            if (((string)value).Length > 0)
                age = Int32.Parse((String)value);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false, $"Illegal characters or {e.Message}");
        }

        if ((age < Min) || (age > Max))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false,
              $"Please enter an age in the range: {Min}-{Max}.");
        }
        return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
    }
}
```

If that doesn't work, then this answer may be helpful: [How do I get a TextBox to only accept numeric input in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268552/how-do-i-get-a-textbox-to-only-accept-numeric-input-in-wpf)

Otherwise, this can also be done by implementing some form of `DataTrigger`.

A `DataTrigger` "Represents a trigger that applies property values or performs actions when the bound data meets a specified condition."

See Microsoft's documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.datatrigger?view=windowsdesktop-6.0).

An example pulled from their page shows how you can change the foreground color of a `ListBoxItem` conditionally, based on the text property of a `Place` object:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <c:Places x:Key="PlacesData"/>

  <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=State}" Value="WA">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
      </DataTrigger>    
      <MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
          <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Value="Portland" />
          <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=State}" Value="OR" />
        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Cyan" />
      </MultiDataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>

  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type c:Place}">
    <Canvas Width="160" Height="20">
      <TextBlock FontSize="12"
             Width="130" Canvas.Left="0" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
      <TextBlock FontSize="12" Width="30"
                 Canvas.Left="130" Text="{Binding Path=State}"/>
    </Canvas>
  </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
  <TextBlock FontSize="18" Margin="5" FontWeight="Bold"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center">Data Trigger Sample</TextBlock>
  <ListBox Width="180" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Honeydew"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource PlacesData}}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Alternatively (or perhaps additionally), you may need to use some sort of converter with your binding. It's possible to have a string converter that replaces all instances of a character with another character and return the transformed string to a binding. See some of Microsoft's documentation on converters [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-convert-bound-data?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Comment: And yet I don't understand how to change exactly the entered character

Comment: I just added a section at the top regarding data validation as well, in case you wanted it to be validated on the user side. However, it seems you want to do the change yourself, so I believe the `DataTrigger` with `Converter` would work best. I will update my answer with more.

Comment: `<TextBox TextChanged="Entry_TextChanged"/>`  When using this method, immediately after entering the dot character, it changes to the input of the subsequent text, does not continue in the same place, but begins from the beginning of the textbox bypassing another written text

Comment: If you modify the text within your `TextChanged` event, you'll probably have to unsubscribe form the text changed event and then subscribe to the event again once you have changed the text programatically. Updated my code to show pseudocode for it. Beyond that, you'll probably need to write your code and post a new question that is more on topic and contains the code you've tried. Your current question is too vague as there are too many ways to do what you are asking.